# Does Take() increase performance in EF Core?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I am working on a messenger, my current logic of loading messages is to get messages from the database order them by date and take 20 from, then pass them to the client, just like telegram, when the user scrolls to the top, server pass more messages and same logic for the end of messages.

Actually, I am simulating lazy loading but I don't know is it really lazy loading? I want to know if the `Order` and `Take` queries will get all the messages?

Does `Take` increase performance? If not, how should I implement this situation?

Comment: The documentation for EF Core has some interesting information on [Pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/pagination).

Comment: use logging and/or LINQPad to see what SQL your LINQ queries generate

Comment: Pagination is *always* a good idea, when you work with a lot of entities. However, you should only sort by an indexed column, otherwise it's gonna be really slow.

Comment: You're mixing up several concepts and patterns. Try to untangle them and focus on paging alone. Then *maybe* one clear programming question will remain that's on topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are various things to consider here, given your requirements for a date-based pagination, you will need to add a new column, to be used as an efficient index, to encapsulate the date ( NOT the time ) of each post.
So for you table of "Posts", along with any "Created" field, that probably keeps a full timestamp, add a new Column of (Date) only field ( or string would be even better, given that you would use a sortable-string represantation of the date only part )

So this would cover the proper setup db-wise, and this is because there is no better place to do ANY sorting, especially if you need to be able to scale big.

So haviing an efficient index column ready will allow you orderBy, Skip(loaded) and Take(NextPageCount), in a single async query, that EF will produce and your db will be able to optimise for.